# Can access site from external network, but not from internal network

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.4, port-forwarding, local-area-network, web-applications

I have registered a domain name (say leavemanager.somecompany.com), it points to a web based application (web app) hosted in a windows server machine running apache2. I have port forwarded http/s traffic of the server LAN address 192.168.0.x in the router to the external IP of the router.

**When I try access the web app from an external network using the domain name, it works perfectly,** but **when I try access from a machine in the LAN using the same domain name, the web app does not load at all and browser says it cannot find the page.** What could be the problem?

Comment: "browser says it cannot find the page.".  Obviously first things to do would be to test name resolution. You are not giving however enough important information in your question for anyone to help.

Comment: Hi @PatrickMevzek Kindly let me know what information I have left out so that I share.

Comment: Try to start with the real name involved maybe... Do proper troubleshooting using DNS and HTTP clients (`dig` and `wget` for example) and share actual traces of what works, what does not (without using images).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You must set your Firewall to redirect the traffic from the internal IP range(s) to the internal IP of the Server 192.168.0.x, for the port and traffic type.